# Auto mounting vmware virtual disk on ubuntu startup

Tags: 11.10, vmware, fstab

How do I mount a vmware vmdk file as /home on startup?

I have been using Ubuntu as a VMWare Guest. All My data resides on a single vmdk disk, which I mounted as /home in the VM using fstab. Now I want to move to an actual Ubuntu installtion for performance reasons (Installed with wubi under windows 7). I can mount my vmdk to a folder using vmware-mount (I have vmware server), but how do I go about mounting it to /home on startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the command you use to mount your disk, part of a bash script named say, **customMount.sh**. An example of such a script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# File: customMount.sh
# Description: Mounts a partition on startup
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home
```

Above script will mount /dev/sda1 (first physical partition on sda) to /home. *Note: Replace it with your vmware-mount command.*

Then run following commands:

1. Make customMount.sh executable
   `sudo chmod +x customMount.sh`
2. Copy to /etc/init.d
   `cp customMount.sh /etc/init.d/`
3. Change directory to /etc/rc5.d/ and make a link to the script as:
   `cd /etc/rc5.d`
   `ln -s ../init.d/customMount.sh S20customMount.sh`
4. Similarly, make another link in rc2.d as:
   `cd /etc/rc2.d`
   `ln -s ../init.d/customMount.sh S20customMount.sh`

Reboot Ubuntu and verify if the mounting is done by executing  `ls /home`

Answer (score 3):

"For performance reasons" -- then you don't want to be mounting it via vmware-mount.  Instead, transfer the files out of the vmware image file to /home.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I still get a major improvement when I am running ubuntu as the only OS. and I need to keep the vmdk to take on the road and sometimes when I quickly need to do something in ubuntu and I'm in windows

Comment: This post unfortunately doesn't answer my question in its current state